# Why does the output to my quadratic equation function in Haskell, return (NaN, NaN)?

Tags: haskell

I have a question, the output to my function here gives (NaN, NaN). Did I miss something in the code or?

```
roots :: (Float, Float, Float) -> (Float, Float)
roots (a,b,c) = 
    let s = sqrt (b*b - 4.0*a*c)
        d = 2.0*a
    in ((-b + s)/d, (-b - s)/d)
```

I searched up and found that NaN is not a number, but why is it displaying when I execute my quadratic equation code in Haskell?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since the roots can be complex, they can't be represented in a `Float` in all cases. A possible fix is to switch the result type to involve `Complex Float`, which stores both the real and imaginary part.

Below, `x :+ y` stands for a complex number with real part `x` and imaginary part `y`.

```
import Data.Complex

roots :: (Float, Float, Float) 
      -> (Complex Float, Complex Float)
roots (a,b,c) = 
    let s = sqrt ((b*b - 4.0*a*c) :+ 0)
        d = 2.0*a :+ 0
        b' = b :+ 0
    in ((-b' + s)/d, (-b' - s)/d)
```

Now, complex roots are printed instead of `NaN`s.

```
> roots (1,0,1)
(0.0 :+ 1.0,(-0.0) :+ (-1.0))
```

(Note that if `a` is zero we can still get a `NaN` if we try to compute `0/0`. But that's a distinct issue.)

By the way, in Haskell we usually define functions in their curried form, i.e.

```
roots :: Float -> Float -> Float 
      -> (Complex Float, Complex Float)
roots a b c = ...
```